# Set Up Cron Job on Amzon EC2 Not Working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I want to set up cron job on amazon ec2 which insert the data in table every minute. I have followed many tutorials but I am not able to get this sorted out.
I got this email in instance that file not exit

```
  Subject: Cron <ec2-user@ip-11-----> /src/bin/php/var/www/html/test.php
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
  X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
  X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
  X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ec2-user>
  X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
  X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ec2-user>
  X-Cron-Env: <USER=ec2-user>



/bin/sh: /src/bin/php/var/www/html/test.php: No such file or directory
```

I have the test.php inside html folder which normally reside in `/var/www/html`

I am setting the cron in crontab using following line of code

```
* * * * * /src/bin/php/var/www/html/test.php
```

I don't what is the issue why cron is not working.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /src/bin/php/var/www/html/test.php`

Comment: @helloV ls: cannot access /src/bin/php/var/www/html/test.php: No such file or directory

Comment: then fix it. You may not have permissions to access the file. Did you add this crontab entry for the user who can access this file?

Comment: @helloV can you please help how to set permission for that

Comment: See the solution posted by @Joseph. Most likely you are missing a space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, perhaps do you try this ??

```
* * * * * /src/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php
```

> With a space between /php and /var

/src/bin/php -> this part is in order to be able to execute php scripts/files.

/var/www/html/test.php -> this is the script/file that you want to execute.

Don't worry it also happens to me. Just check it.

Best regards.

Comment: Good catch. He most likely missed a space.